# Copy and paste a formula every n rows until end of array

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Having some trouble finding a solution to copying and pasting formulas every n row. I've investigated FormulaR1C1 function but could not find a solution. Was wondering if anyone could help me out.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
Col1 Col2
A1 =formula(A1)
A2 ----skip line -----
A3 ----skip line ------
A4 ----skip line ------
A5 ----skip line ------
A6 ----skip line ------
A7 ----skip line ------
A8 ----skip line ------
A9 ----skip line ------
A10 ----skip line ------
A11 =formula(A11)
A12 ----skip line ------
A13 ----skip line ------
A14 ----skip line ------
A15 ----skip line ------
A16 ----skip line ------
A17 ----skip line ------
A18 ----skip line ------
A19 ----skip line ------
A20 ----skip line ------
A21 =formula(A21)
```

FOR ADDITIONAL CLARIFICATION:

The formula is an array with a ten row / two column output so you cannot copy and paste a formula down.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: That is correct. It should always be 10 rows.

Comment: I've made some additional clarifications. Any further help?

Comment: Sorry about that. It's fixed. Do you have the VBA code to help me out?

Comment: Show the formula so we can simulate. Also any effort you've tried to solve your problem. Have you tried `.FormulaArray` property?

Answer (score -1):

you can select n cells with the formula in the first cell then click the black point in the lower right part of the selection and drag the mouse down or use a formula that returns "=formula(A2&"text")" only every n-th time:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),n)=2,formula(A2&"text"),"""")
```

Comment: This does work but the formula is an array formula and when you copy and paste down it says you cannot change part of an array. Sorry for not being more clear.